# Can you use devtools inside the Edge mobile app?

Tags: mobile, microsoft-edge, devtools

Not sure if this is possible in other mobile browsers, but it is possible to open the devtools inside the Edge browser app in you phone?

I have this UI issue that that I can see on my phone and so far I haven't been able to reproduce it on Edge desktop  or any other desktop browser for that matter; not even if I match the screen size using the dekstop devtools.

I need Edge mobile devtools specifically because the website is internal and only accessible through Edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devtools are not available for Edge mobile.

If you want to debug the Edge mobile app, you can use **Device Mode** to simulate mobile devices in your desktop Edge Chromium browser. For the detailed steps, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/device-mode/).

If you're using Android devices, you can even use **remote debugging**. It can remote debug live content on an Android device from your Windows or macOS computer. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with help of [eruda](https://github.com/liriliri/eruda) project

1. Add bookmark on any website, name it as Open  DevTools, put this script as a value

```js
javascript:(function () {var script=document.createElement('script');script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda";document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();
```

2. Open website you would like to investigate
3. Open search bar and enter same name, Open DevTools - your bookmark will appear
   [image]
4. Click on it, few seconds later you will see gear icon on the bottom. Click on this icon will open dev tools
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

On iOS (not sure for android) there is `edge://inspect` page that can give you logs from open tabs. Not that much great but better than nothing.